# Multiple Vuetify data-tables with expandable rows on same page

Tags: vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm using Vuetify's v-data-tables with expandable rows. The expandable rows work fine when there's only one v-data-table on the page. When I have multiple v-data-tables, the expandable rows no longer function. I'm assuming I'm missing something that would make each data table or slot unique?

CodePen: https://codepen.io/tapal/pen/poyOdBw (this is essentially the expandable rows CodePen from  Vuetify's documentation but split into two tables).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      expanded: [],
      singleExpand: false,
      headers: [{
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        {
          text: 'Calories',
          value: 'calories'
        },
        {
          text: 'Fat (g)',
          value: 'fat'
        },
        {
          text: 'Carbs (g)',
          value: 'carbs'
        },
        {
          text: 'Protein (g)',
          value: 'protein'
        },
        {
          text: 'Iron (%)',
          value: 'iron'
        },
        {
          text: '',
          value: 'data-table-expand'
        },
      ],
      firstDessert: [{
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
      ],
      secondDessert: [{
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.10/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="firstDessert" :single-expand="singleExpand" :expanded.sync="expanded" item-key="name" show-expand class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:top>
            <v-toolbar flat>
              <v-toolbar-title>First Dessert</v-toolbar-title>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-switch v-model="singleExpand" label="Single expand" class="mt-2"></v-switch>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">More info about {{ item.name }}</td>
          </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <hr />
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="secondDessert" :single-expand="singleExpand" :expanded.sync="expanded" item-key="name" show-expand class="elevation-1">
      <template v-slot:top>
            <v-toolbar flat>
              <v-toolbar-title>Second Dessert</v-toolbar-title>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-switch v-model="singleExpand" label="Single expand" class="mt-2"></v-switch>
            </v-toolbar>
          </template>
      <template v-slot:expanded-item="{ headers, item }">
            <td :colspan="headers.length">More info about {{ item.name }}</td>
          </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think your problem is arising from there being two data-tables, remove the one and it still doenst work

Comment: CodePen with the second data table removed: https://codepen.io/tapal/pen/vYGzdVd. Expandable rows working for me.

Comment: I don't know for sure why it worked but setting the expanded prop of each table to sync to two separate properties seems to work

Comment: You're right, the expanded prop was the issue. I actually I removed the :expanded.sync="expanded" all together since I'm adding the v-data-tables dynamically and it still works. Thought that was required. Thanks for the help.